# get file content and name with jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Help me to get file content and name with jquery and php?

In a form with method post and enctype="multipart/form-data" page:

```
$("#chat-form").submit(function(){
  var message = $("#message").val();
  var file = $("#file").val();
  $("#chat-act").load("ctn/chat-act.php",{
    message: message,
    file: file
  });
});
```

In **ctn/chat-act.php**

```
$message = trim(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['message']))); 
$file = @$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$name_file = @$_FILES['file']['name'];
echo $message.'<br>'.$file.'<br>'.$name_file;
```